# How to determine the best predictor of an attribute given an array using python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, chi-squared

Given the following data set, I'd like to use Python's statistical libraries to show what factor is the best predictor of the highest value.

```
array = [{'region':'europe','fruit':'orange','value':1,'color':'orange'},{'region':'europe','fruit':'pineapple','value':1,'color':'brown'},{'region':'europe','fruit':'banana','value':1,'color':'yellow'},{'region':'america','fruit':'orange','value':5,'color':'orange'},{'region':'australia','fruit':'apple','value':6,'color':'red'},{'region':'asia','fruit':'apple','value':6,'color':'red'}]
```

Above is mock data that shows that 'Europe' is the worst predictor of a high value, since it always is associated with a value of 1, while 'Apple' is the best predictor since it's always associated with a value of 6.

I'm unsure how to go about utilizing python for this whether it's utilizing scikit, numpy, pandas, etc.

I'm currently trying to utilize [chi-square tests](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html) by looking at each key-value pair (e.g. 'region':'europe', 'fruit':'orange') and aggregating their values and using 3.33 as the expected value multiplied by the number of instances (since the aggregate total of all the values is 20 and there are 6 items). I can post my code and error, but I'm not sure if using chi-squares is the way to go.

Comment: You could build a decision tree of depth 1. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)

Comment: Having 6 observations is definitely not enough to build any model on your data. It's like trying to light a match with a flamethrower.

Comment: I completely agree. That was just an example. Imagine that array was multiplied 1000 times over. In such a case, how would I go about determining the best predicting attribute.